# i download some code from github and i try to require it into my nodejs project?

Tags: node.js, npm

Because i can't install "bcrypt" in my windows 8.1, so i download "bcrypt" source code. so, how to require it into my project? is it using require command or other methods?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pure javascript version of bcrypt:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs

I don't think it's going to be easy to use the "normal" bcrypt library on a windows machine.

Comment: i've download the pure version from the github(just as the picture shows)but i don't know how require into my node project

Comment: You should use `npm install bcryptjs --save` in your nodejs project. Don't download source code unless you absolutely need to!

Comment: If npm install is not working, you should reinstall node.